# Django. Why would my foreign key does not match the same data from parent primary key

Tags: python, django

I have 2 models:

```
class Director(models.Model):
    director_name = models.TextField(primary_key=True)
    director_firstname = models.CharField(max_length=32)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.director_name}'

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('director-detail', args=[str(self.director_name)])

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'director'
        ordering = ['director_name']

class Connection(models.Model):
    director_connect = models.ForeignKey('Director', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='director_connect')
    worker_connect = models.ForeignKey('Worker', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='worker_connect')

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'connection'
        unique_together = (('director_connect', 'worker_connect'),)
        ordering = ['director_connect']

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.director_connect}'

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('director-detail', args=[str(self.director_connect)])
```

This is my view.py file:

```
class DirectorDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model=Director
    template_name = 'company/director_detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **qwargs):
        a = super(DirectorDetailView, self).get_context_data(**qwargs)
        a['cons'] = Connection.objects.all()
        return a
```

When I am trying to match 2 columns in html with for loop and if statement, they do not match, although they are similar one to one copies of each other:

```
{% extends "index.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <h1>{{ director.director_name }}</h1>
    <p>{{ director.firstname }}</p>
    {% for con in cons %}
        {% if object.director_name == con.director_connect %}
            <li>{{con.id}}, {{con.director_connect}}, {{con.worker_connect}}</li>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

How could I fix it? I would like to bring the list of workers under director's name. Any link to probable answer (I was looking for it, but I couldn't find it) or slight push towards the right direction would be nice.

Comment: Try changing the if expression to `{% if object == con.director_connect %}`. I believe the issue is that you're trying to compare the director's name with the primary key thats referenced in the connection. You could also try filtering in the backend using `Connection.objects.filter(director_connect=self.get_object()).all()` or maybe use a [ManyToManyField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/)

Comment: Thank you, Eduardo! It helped... The foreign key is a reference. Somehow I didn't realized it, till your help...

Comment: Please, I realize, it is probably small question... But could you please post your very same text into the answer, so I can mark this question as answered and give you some rep points? Thank you for help again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that in your template you're comparing the director's name with the primary key that's referenced in the `Connection` by means of the director_connect `ForeignKey`. The simplest solution would be to change the if expression:

```
{% extends "index.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <h1>{{ director.director_name }}</h1>
    <p>{{ director.firstname }}</p>
    {% for con in cons %}
        {% if object == con.director_connect %}  // Change it so it compares the primary key
            <li>{{con.id}}, {{con.director_connect}}, {{con.worker_connect}}</li>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Other way to achieve this would be to filter the workers by director in the view, using filter:

```
class DirectorDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model=Director
    template_name = 'company/director_detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **qwargs):
        a = super(DirectorDetailView, self).get_context_data(**qwargs)
        director = self.get_object()
        a['cons'] = Connection.objets.filter(direct_connect=director).all()
        return a
```

This is better because it will filter the workers in the database using SQL which is probably faster than the template engine.

Other solution would be to use a [ManyToManyField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) and let django ORM take care of the relations for you, but that would require refactoring the code and maybe some database migrations.